# How to pass environment to map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two questions:
1. Why can't I pass `rows` to `checkEdge` while I can pass `rowIndex` to `checkEdge`?
2. How can I can give access all arguments/variables of `createBoard` to `checkEdge` without having to pass all of them as `checkEdge(cell, cellIndex, rowIndex, width, height)`
?
Tried `checkEdge.apply(arguments)` and `checkEdge.bind(this)` but it didn't work.

```
const checkEdge = function(cell, cellIndex, rows, rowIndex, width, height) {
  console.log(rows) // <--- logs undefined.
  console.log(rowIndex) // <--- works as expected.
  if(rowIndex === 0 || rowIndex === height-1) {
    return {value: 0, birth: false}
  }
  else if(cellIndex === 0 || cellIndex === width-1) {
    return { value: 0, birth: false }
  }
  else {
    return { value: Math.round(Math.random()), birth: false }
  }
}

const createBoard = ({width,height}) =>
Array.from({length: height}, 
  (rows, rowIndex) => Array.from({length: width}, (cell, cellIndex) => 

    checkEdge(cell, cellIndex, rows, rowIndex, width, height)
  ) 
)
```

Comment: You can pass `rows`, but you are not passing that variable to the `checkEdge` function. It's unclear what you are asking. Also what are you trying to achieve when using `Array.from` ?

Comment: @Cristy if I pass it like checkEdge(cell, cellIndex, rows, rowIndex, width, height) and execute like function(cell, cellIndex, rows, rowIndex, width, height) it returns undefined if i console.log(rows) inside checkEdge while console.log(rowIndex) works. And i'm creating an array containing arrays of objects with {value, birth}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I pass `rows` to `checkEdge` while I can pass `rowIndex` to `checkEdge`?

You can, and you do. The problem is just that `rows` is `undefined`, just like `cell` in the inner `Array.from`. Notice you are creating the array from nothing (just an object with a length but no elements), there are no values yet.

> How can I can give access all arguments/variables of `createBoard` to `checkEdge` without having to pass all of them as `checkEdge(cell, cellIndex, rowIndex, width, height)`?

You cannot use `arguments` because they don't exist in arrow functions. You could use rest syntax, but it wouldn't be particularly helpful here either. In general, while there's the possibility to use helper functions (e.g. from the [Ramda library](http://ramdajs.com/)) that allow us to write [point-free code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming), explicit parameter passing is much simpler (and more readable anyway) here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the spread/rest syntax:

```
const createBoard = ({width,height}) =>
Array.from(
  {length: height}, 
  (...b) => Array.from(
     {length: width}, 
     (...a) =>checkEdge(...a, ...b, width, height)
  ) 
);
```